# How is $\frac{ds}{dt}$ related to $\frac{dx}{dt}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The problem states: ***Let $x$ and $y$ be differentiable functions of $t$, and let $s = \sqrt{4x^2+6y^2}$ be a function of $x$ and $y$. How is $\frac{ds}{dt}$ related to $\frac{dx}{dt}$ if $y$ is constant?***

My attempt:

\begin{align}
\frac{ds}{dt} & = \frac{d}{dt} \left( \sqrt{4x^2+6y^2} \right) \\
 & = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{4x^2+6y^2}}*\left(8x\frac{dx}{dt}+12y\frac{dy}{dt}\right)
\end{align}

If $y$ is constant, then $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$

\begin{align}
\frac{ds}{dt} & = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{4x^2+6y^2}}*\left(8x\frac{dx}{dt}+12y*0\right)\\
& =\left(\frac{8x}{2\sqrt{4x^2+6y^2}}\right)*\frac{dx}{dt}
\end{align}

This is the relation I have found, but it is not correct. What is the relation between $\frac{ds}{dt}$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}$ ?

Comment: Do you have the correct answer?

Comment: I do not and I am still unsure. Will hopefully get the answer in class in an hour.

Comment: This appears correct. Did you ever get the answer?

Comment: Maybe all they're asking for is $\dfrac{ds}{dt} = \dfrac{ds}{dx} \times \dfrac{dx}{dt}$ ? And then you can work it out as you have done.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the usefulness of Leibniz notation in dealing with these sorts of problems.

$$\frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{ds}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$$

This, intuitively, is because the $dx$'s "cancel out".

All to do here is to find $\frac{ds}{dx}$.

Since $y$ is not a function of $x$, we can treat it as constant. Therefore:

$$\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt} \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \left[\sqrt{4x^2+6y^2} \right]$$

And since $$\frac{d}{dx} \left[\sqrt{4x^2+6y^2} \right] = \frac{4x}{\sqrt{4x^2+6y^2}}$$

The only difference I can find is that you did not simplify your answer. To find out more, how exactly did you know your answer is incorrect?

Comment: This question was from when I was taking Calc I, to answer your question about my answer being incorrect, I do not know. I was never able to get the answer iirc. The question was from MyMathLab, so at this point I would say either I misunderstood the question being asked (although I posted the question verbatim) or some internal error was messing it up. The solution posed by Airdish seems like it could be a solution. Maybe it was a matter with that simplification but that seems too trivial to have overlooked, maybe not.